# Перенос строки jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Желаемый результат:
При нажатии на enter-отправляется запрос,при нажатии ctrl+enter-перенос строки.(работает)
Проблема:
Перенос строки делается не там,где стоит курсор,а всегда в конце написанного текста,прошу помочь с этим вопросом,заранее спасибо.
html:

```
<div></div>
<form action="/" id="form" method="post">
<textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#textarea').keypress(function(e) {
if(window.event) {
  var keyCode = window.event.keyCode;     
}
else {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
}

if( (!e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) ) {
   e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
        $( "div" ).css("display", "block").text("Отправлено!");
        });
   }else if( (e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) || (keyCode == 10) ) {
   this.value += "\n";
   }                  
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там по ссылке в комментарии поподробнее. А просто и возможно не для всех браузеров

```js
$('#textarea').keypress(function(e) {
if(window.event) {
  var keyCode = window.event.keyCode;     
}
else {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
}

if( (!e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) ) {

   e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
        $( "div" ).css("display", "block").text("Отправлено!");
        });
   }else if( (e.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 13)) || (keyCode == 10) ) {
      caretStart = this.selectionStart;
      caretEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      this.value = (this.value.substring(0, caretStart)
              + "\n"
              + this.value.substring(caretEnd));
   }                  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<form action="/" id="form" method="post">
<textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```